# C# Linq Inner Join

Tags: c#, linq

I want to select the persons  only who are having pets.

when I execute the query

```
var query = from p in people
                        join
                        pts in pets
                        on p equals pts.Owner into grp
                        select new {grp=grp,PersonName=p.FirstName};
```

Person does not have pet also get selected.

My Lists are

```
Person[] prn = new Person[3];
prn[0] = new Person();
prn[0].FirstName = "Jon";
prn[0].LastName = "Skeet";

prn[1] = new Person();
prn[1].FirstName = "Marc";
prn[1].LastName = "Gravell";

prn[2] = new Person();
prn[2].FirstName = "Alex";
prn[2].LastName = "Grover";

List<Person> people = new List<Person>();

 foreach (Person p in prn)
 {
     people.Add(p);
 }

 Pet[] pt = new Pet[3];

 pt[0] = new Pet();
 pt[0].Name = "Zonny";
 pt[0].Owner = people[0];

pt[1] = new Pet();
pt[1].Name = "Duggie";
pt[1].Owner = people[0];

pt[2] = new Pet();
pt[2].Name = "Zoggie";
pt[2].Owner = people[1];

List<Pet> pets=new List<Pet>();
 foreach(Pet p in pt)
 {
    pets.Add(p);
 }
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

That's because you're using `join ... into` which does a group join. You just want a normal join:

```
var query = (from p in people
             join pts in pets on p equals pts.Owner
             select p).Distinct();
```

Alternatively, if you want the people with pets, and their owners, you could do something like:

```
var query = pets.GroupBy(pet => pet.Owner)
                .Select(x => new { Owner = x.Key, Pets = x.ToList() });
```

That will give a result where you can get each owner and their pets, but only for people who *have* pets.

If you want something else, let us know...

By the way, now would be a good time to learn about object and collection initializers. Here's a simpler way to initialize your `people` list, for example:

```
List<Person> people = new List<Person>
{
    new Person { FirstName = "Jon", LastName = "Skeet" },
    new Person { FirstName = "Marc", LastName = "Gravell" },
    new Person { FirstName = "Alex", LastName = "Grover" },
};
```

Much more compact :)

EDIT: A cross join is easy:

```
var query = from person in people
            from pet in pets
            select new { person, pet };
```

Left joins are effectively emulated using group joins. As it sounds like you've got C# in Depth, I suggest you read chapter 11 thoroughly :)

Comment: 'into grp' should be gone, not?  ;p

Comment: See you fixed it :)  The 'into' changes the lexical scope kinda which always confuses me outside the IDE.

Comment: yes i have read that simple way initialization from your book.

Comment: Yes I want something more ,I mean can  you explain how can  i perform outer join (left,right) ,inner join,cross join in Linq.

Comment: Sure I  will look at Chapter 11 throughly. Have you worked out any examples on your MisUtil ?

Comment: I mean,I want to do some Zip like functionality as in C# 4.0

Comment: If you want to use Zip, have a look at MoreLinq: http://code.google.com/p/morelinq

Answer (score 6):

Here's a different way to do it, adding only one line:

```
var query = from p in people
            join pts in pets
            on p equals pts.Owner into grp
            where grp.Any()             // <--- added this
            select new {grp=grp,PersonName=p.FirstName};
```

Here I select the groups, as you do, but I added one line that selects only the groups that contain at least one element, and ignore the rest.

Answer (score 5):

this can also be done using lambda expressions in a single line of code...

```
IEnumerable<Person> peopleWithPets = people.Where(x => pets.Any(y => y.Owner == x));
```

Comment: How would you select properties from either or both? For e.g., I need to select x.PetName and y.PetName